# JQuery .prop() on click checked > false

Tags: jquery, click, checked, prop

I have a form with checkboxes which generates a new block displaying the color filters selected by the user.

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syGE3.png)

In this new block, I made a click event which removes the selected filter with the ".buttonRemoveFilter" button.

I try to uncheck the checkbox in conjunction with the filter but I can only uncheck all the checkboxes.

```
$(document).on("click", ".buttonRemoveFilter", function(){

     $("[id^=branche_search_form_couleurs_").prop("checked", false);
     $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

I try to do, that when I remove a filter from the new block, it unchecks the color checkbox related to this filter.

[New block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myrzB.png)

```
<div class="poPupFiltre">
  <div class="sousBlockPoPup">
    <button class="buttonRemoveFilter">
      <img class="img-fluid imgPoPup" src="{{ asset ('../build/images/supprimer.svg') }}" alt="">
    </button>
    <p class="textPopUp"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try `$(this).parents().remove()` ?

Comment: yes i tried but it breaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a way of knowing which filter you have clicked - if you want to remove BLANC filter, check that the user has clicked BLANC filter type. Then access checkbox input by using

```
$("input[value='"+clickedFilterType+"']")
```

Something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".buttonRemoveFilter", function(){
     let clickedFilterType = $(this).attr("data-type");
     $("input[value='"+clickedFilterType+"']").prop("checked", false);

});
```

Comment: I used your proposal by adding in my function which generates the filter:  
 $newDivCouleur.attr("type", $(this).val());  
and after that:  
let clickedFilterType = $(this).parent().parent().attr("type");  
 $("input[value='"+clickedFilterType+"']").prop("checked", false);  
the result is impeccable!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try these options.

In your form add a common class to your input checkbox (let's say the class name is ".chxbox")

Then use this jQuery function

```
   $('.chxbox').click(function(){
         id = $(this).attr('id');
         $(id).prop('checked',false);
         $(this).remove();
    });
```